# Looking to set up a Dell PowerVault LTO-6 tape drive on Ubuntu Server using LTFS file system

Tags: software-installation

I recently purchased a Dell PowerVault LTO-6 tape drive to use with my server running Ubuntu 14.04.3. It's connected via mini-SAS.

I want to set up the tape drive so that I can format LTO-6 tapes using the LTFS file system, so that I can see the LTO-6 tape as if it's an external disk drive, dragging and dropping files in to it to copy them to the tape.

*What should I do to get the above described functionality out of my system?*

Here's the output to: `sudo mt -f /dev/st0 status`

```
drive type = 114
drive status = 1509949440
sense key error = 0
residue count = 0
file number = 0
block number = 0
```

The output to `lsusb&&lspci`:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:a001 Dell Computer Corp. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b3:310d IBM Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DMI2 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 02)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 02)
00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Address Map, VTd_Misc, System Management (rev 02)
00:05.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Hot Plug (rev 02)
00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E RAS, Control Status and Global Errors (rev 02)
00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Haswell-E I/O Apic (rev 02)
00:11.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation Wellsburg SPSR (rev 05)
00:11.4 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Wellsburg sSATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wellsburg MEI Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:16.1 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wellsburg MEI Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wellsburg USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wellsburg PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wellsburg PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wellsburg PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wellsburg PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wellsburg USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wellsburg LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Wellsburg SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
03:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader] (rev 02)
04:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS3008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-3 (rev 02)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Renesas Technology Corp. Device 001d
07:00.0 PCI bridge: Renesas Technology Corp. Device 001d
08:00.0 PCI bridge: Renesas Technology Corp. Device 001a
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2 (rev 01)
7f:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
7f:08.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
7f:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
7f:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
7f:09.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
7f:09.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
7f:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
7f:0b.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
7f:0b.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
7f:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0d.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
7f:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
7f:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
7f:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
7f:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
7f:0f.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
7f:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCIe Ring Interface (rev 02)
7f:10.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCIe Ring Interface (rev 02)
7f:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
7f:10.6 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
7f:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
7f:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 0 (rev 02)
7f:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 0 (rev 02)
7f:12.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 0 Debug (rev 02)
7f:12.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 1 (rev 02)
7f:12.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 1 (rev 02)
7f:12.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 1 Debug (rev 02)
7f:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
7f:13.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
7f:13.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:13.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:13.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast (rev 02)
7f:13.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 02)
7f:14.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
7f:14.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
7f:14.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
7f:14.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
7f:14.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
7f:14.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
7f:14.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
7f:14.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
7f:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
7f:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
7f:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:16.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:16.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast (rev 02)
7f:16.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 02)
7f:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
7f:17.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
7f:17.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
7f:17.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 1 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
7f:17.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
7f:17.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
7f:17.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
7f:17.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
7f:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
7f:1f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E VCU (rev 02)
7f:1f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E VCU (rev 02)
80:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCI Express Root Port 0 (rev 02)
80:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 02)
80:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 02)
80:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 02)
80:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Address Map, VTd_Misc, System Management (rev 02)
80:05.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Hot Plug (rev 02)
80:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E RAS, Control Status and Global Errors (rev 02)
80:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Haswell-E I/O Apic (rev 02)
ff:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:08.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
ff:09.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
ff:09.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
ff:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
ff:0b.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
ff:0b.2 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring (rev 02)
ff:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0d.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Unicast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
ff:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
ff:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
ff:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Buffered Ring Agent (rev 02)
ff:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
ff:0f.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers (rev 02)
ff:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCIe Ring Interface (rev 02)
ff:10.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E PCIe Ring Interface (rev 02)
ff:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
ff:10.6 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
ff:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers (rev 02)
ff:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 0 (rev 02)
ff:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 0 (rev 02)
ff:12.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 0 Debug (rev 02)
ff:12.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 1 (rev 02)
ff:12.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 1 (rev 02)
ff:12.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Home Agent 1 Debug (rev 02)
ff:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:13.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:13.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:13.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:13.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast (rev 02)
ff:13.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 02)
ff:14.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:14.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:14.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
ff:14.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
ff:14.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
ff:14.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
ff:14.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
ff:14.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 (rev 02)
ff:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:16.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:16.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast (rev 02)
ff:16.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO Global Broadcast (rev 02)
ff:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:17.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:17.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
ff:17.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 1 ERROR Registers (rev 02)
ff:17.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
ff:17.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
ff:17.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
ff:17.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 (rev 02)
ff:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E Power Control Unit (rev 02)
ff:1f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E VCU (rev 02)
ff:1f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Haswell-E VCU (rev 02)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb&&lspci`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: Hey @Fabby thanks for the reply! I ran the commands you asked (as well as 'mt -f /dev/st0 status' to ensure the server is recognizing the drive, which it looks like it is); see my original post for the results. At this point, I think I need to either download and install some Linux tape backup software, or LTFS software from IBM (apparently Dell tape drives are just re-branded IBM drives so IBM drivers should work?), or maybe both?

Comment: I looked at the binaries and there doesn't seem to be a Debian nor Ubuntu version around (a `.deb` file) on the Quantum site... looking further if I can find a ppa.  Otherwise you're basically the first one that's going to try to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry to say, but there is no pre-compiled Ubuntu version of `qtmltfs2.1.2-2` that I can find anywhere, so you'll have to [download the source code](http://www.quantum.com/serviceandsupport/opensource/ltfs/index.aspx) and [compile and make it yourself](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/compiling-quantum-ltfs-software-on-debian-894103/) :

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev uuid uuid-dev libicu-dev libxml++2.6-2 libxml++2.6-dev  build-essential
cd /home/$USER/qtmltfs-2.1.2-2/ 
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: Better with `sudo checkinstall` instead of `sudo make install`

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try today. Once I have that finished (hopefully successful), will I still need some backup software like Bacula? Or will the Quantum LTFS software allow me to format tapes using LTFS partitioning, which will then allow them to appear as a disk drive in Ubuntu?

Comment: @A.B.: edited!  **;-)**

Comment: @Jesse: LTFS is just a file system module, so yes, you still need some kind of back-up software.  (I'm unfamiliar with Bacula though)  And LTFS is actually supposed to make OS-independant tapes, so I would use `rsync` instead of some specialised back-up software.

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!